# Postfix appending AUTH= to envelope sender prevents delivery

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

When using `AUTH`, postfix adds `AUTH=<>` to the envelope sender.  This causes a CrossBox server to reject the message:

```
220  CrossBox SMTP Proxify # 232 (1) Fri, 04 Jan 2019 08:13:35 +0000
EHLO example.com
250-Hello example.com[x.x.x.x]
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250 AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
AUTH LOGIN
[digest sent]
X.235 Authentication successful
MAIL FROM:<test@example.com> AUTH=<>
501 Was expecting MAIL arg syntax of FROM:<address>
```

If I telnet to the CrossBox server and omit the `AUTH=<>` it works OK.

The CrossBox server is outside my control.  Is there a way I can adjust the postfix settings to still authenticate but prevent `AUTH=<>` being appended?

Currently

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls=no
```

(`smtp_use_tls=no` for testing purposes, so I can tcpdump the interaction)

Comment: Whoever is running that CrossBox is losing a lot more mail than just yours. It might not be under your control, but you should notify whoever runs it.

Comment: Problem has now been reported back to CrossBox, but still interested if there is anything I can do on the postfix side to get it working.